# video.js unable to read local videos

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I've a little video.js player and i'm new to web devlopment.
I want it to read my local videos but i've a message:
"Sorry no compatible source and playback technology were found for this video."

But: If i use the external link given by video.js as sample, i can read the video.

I downloaded some samples to try out. An OGV one worked on the website i downloaded it. But when i try with my own, it doesn't work and show the same error.

Here is the .jsp code :

```
   <div id="videoPlayer">
        <video id="videoClip" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
               controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360"
               poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
               data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>


            <source src="/home/ogda/Bureau/war/src/main/resources/small.ogv type=video/ogg" />
        </video>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var videoPlayer = videojs("videoClip");
        videoPlayer.on("pause", changeVideo);
        //videoPlayer.src("/home/ogda/Bureau/war/src/main/resources/lol.mp4");
        videoPlayer.play();
    </script>
```

Thank you !

EDIT : ANSWER

Commenters were right.
The solution was siomply to put the videos on a webserver !

Comment: I suppose that line is not supposed to be commented out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sandbox problem. The browser does not allow loading local resources for security reasons. If you need it still, use a local webserver on your machine.

Comment: Hanlet it is supposed to, sorry.

weigit i understand why i can't read the video. I should not encounter this problem when i will put the website on a real server ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Its only a problem if you try to use a local file, but it works with URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Most major browsers don't allow you to load in local files, since that poses a security error, e.g. people stealing secure files.

You need to test this on localhost, or setup some other server to test it.

Or, if you're using Chrome, you can turn on the flag that'll allow you to load in local files.

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

run this from command line